# Lie derivative of vectors and Lie derivative of 1-forms: can't reconcile the two

Tags: differential-forms, lie-derivative

I have been studying modern formulations of differential geometry, mostly by reading Flanders, Frankel and Sternberg. I think I have developed a working understanding of the Lie derivative of forms, and vectors, but I am having a hard time with the following paradox. 
Consider a set of basis vectors ${\bf e}_i$ on the manifold. The latter is equipped with a dot product, so that I can also consider the dual basis ${\bf e}^j=g^{ji}\bf{e}_i$. From the definition of the Lie derivative, 
$$
[{\bf e}_i,{\bf e}^j]={\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}{\bf e}^j=g^{jm}[{\bf e}_i,{\bf e}_m]+{\bf e}_i(g^{mj}){\bf e}_m. (*)
$$
In particular, if the ${\bf e}_i$'s commute then ${\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}{\bf e}^j=0$ iff the $g^{ij}$'s are constant. 
Apply this to a holonomic basis ${\bf e}_i=\partial_i$. Then ${\bf e}^j=dx^j$. 
But if I consider $dx^i$ as a 1-form, and apply Cartan's magic formula 
$$
{\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}dx^j=d\delta_i^j=0. (@)
$$
This is what puzzles me. What I am doing wrong? Why are the (*) and (@) results different. Related to that, is the fact that for any vector field
$$
{\cal L}_{\bf X}{\bf X}=0,
$$
while, for the 1-form obtained applying the musical isomorphism to ${\bf X}$ in general
$$
{\cal L}_{\bf X}X^\flat\neq 0.
$$
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is the metric tensor is nonconstant from the viewpoint of the Lie derivative, unless $X$ is Killing.  So this interferes when you try to push Lie derivative inside/outside the musical isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. This answers the second part of my question. But still I can't see why ${\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}{\bf e}^j$ gives a different answer than ${\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}dx^j$.

Comment: Your $\mathbf{e}^j$ is $(\mathbf{e}_j)^\flat$, which is not the same as $\mathrm{d}x^j$ unless $\mathbf{e}_j$ direction split off in the metric.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I was under the impression that $(\partial_i)^\flat=dx^i$.

Comment: That only occurs if $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: I now see my error. Let me see if I get it right. If ${\bf e}_j=\partial_j$, and ${\bf e}^i$ is such that ${\bf e}^i\cdot{\bf e}_j=\delta^i_j$, then $({\bf e}^i)^\flat=dx^i$, and since ${\bf e}^i=g^{ij}{\bf e}_j$, then $dx^i=g^{ij}({\bf e}_j)^\flat$.

Comment: Further, $dx^i$ and ${\bf e}^i$ are isometric, but they are not the same object from the point of view of the Lie derivative.  Thus ${\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}dx^j=0$ but ${\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i}{\bf e}^j\neq 0$ and the commutator  $[{\cal L}_{{\bf e}_i},\flat]\neq 0$.